# How to return empty collection on push

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a problem with the following code. When performing the push inside the collection, I have an item with an empty collection when both conditions are false.

```
$admins = collect(new User);
$owner = collect(new User);

if (config('personal.mailing_technician')) {
    $owner = $event->ticket->ownedBy;
}

if (config('personal.mailing_admin')) {
    $admins = User::query()->role('admin')->get();
}

$sentTo = $admins->push($owner);

if ($senTo->isNotEmpty()) {
    .......
}
```

What could I do to make it empty if both conditions are false?

Comment: make what empty if both conditions are false?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that `$sentTo` is an empty collection when both conditions are false...

```
$admins = collect(new User);
$owner = collect(new User);

if (config('personal.mailing_technician')) {
    $owner = $event->ticket->ownedBy;
}

if (config('personal.mailing_admin')) {
    $admins = User::query()->role('admin')->get();
}

$sentTo = collect(); // Initialize an empty collection

if ($admins->isNotEmpty() || $owner->isNotEmpty()) {
    $sentTo = $admins->push($owner);
}

if ($sentTo->isNotEmpty()) {
    // Do something
}
```